# Intermediate Value Theorom

Tags: calculus, functions

Show that there is at least one negative solution to $e^{x} = -x$

I understand that the intermediate value theorem takes two points to check if the continuous line crosses a section.

How would I start this problem?
Thanks

Comment: I don't think this has a solution

Comment: Oh sorry i wrote down the question wrong it should be e^x not ^-x. I've changed it in the post.

Answer (score 1):

Take 
$$
f(x)=\mathrm{e}^x+x.
$$
Then
$$
f(0)=1>0 \quad\text{and}\quad f(-1)=-1+\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}}<0. 
$$
Hence, Intermediate Value Theorem provides that there exists a $x\in(-1,0)$, where $f$ vanishes.